# Determining number of roots by Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to determine the number of roots of $f(z)=1+6z^3+3z^{10}+z^{11}$ in the annulus $A(0,1,2)$. I cannot conjecture the number of roots and so I am not able to use Rouche's theorem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the number of roots inside the disk $D(0,1)$ by comparison with $6\,z^3$. 
Then, you can determine the roots inside the disk $D(0,2)$ by comparison with $3\,z^{10}$.

How did I guess that? Looking for the largest monomial on $|z|=1$ and $|z|=2$.